# How can I bind Image from XML Element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I've some trouble with binding images from XML doc.
My XML doc is:

```
string xml = "< ?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"? > < Citizens > " +
        "< Citizen >" +
        "< fname > Aziz < /fname >" +
        "< lname>Mirzaev< /lname>" +
        "< pname>Ibrakhimovich< /pname>" +
        "< bday>25.01.1986< /bday>" +            
        "<pic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pic>" +
        "< /Citizen>" +
        "< /Citizens>";
```

and I've class to bind with my ListBox:

```
public class Citizen
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PatronymicName { get; set; }
    public string BirthdayDate { get; set; }
    public BitmapSource Picture { get; set; }

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstName, LastName, PatronymicName); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}{3}{4}", FirstName, LastName, PatronymicName,
            Environment.NewLine, BirthdayDate);
    }
}
```

And there's problem with converting value from XML to BitmapSource or other applied DataTypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because no direct conversion exists between a System.String and a BitmapSource.  You need to create a class that implements the [System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) interface.  This class will receive the bound object value (in this case the value of the `<pic>` element as a string) as input to the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx) method and should return a BitmapSource from that value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Alex. I've created that converter.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(BitmapImage))]
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] val = System.Convert.FromBase64String((String)value);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(val);

        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = ms;
        bi.EndInit();

        return bi;
    }
}
```

BTW the xml's image is not correct image string. Now I just get image from DB direct =).

Thanx Again.